# Linq .Contains or IN

Tags: vb.net, linq

I have the following :

```
  Dim Pols As Model.Batches.Renewals.YYYYY() = RenewAnaFindToYYYY(BegDate, EndDate, BegDate2, EndDate2, True)
        Pols = Pols.Where(Function(x) x.PolicyId = 1440728).ToArray()
```

Now how do I test for a list of PolicyID's ? I want to include PolicyID's {1425427, 1440728, 1695324} in the Array. How do I do this ? Any help would be most appreciated.

Jason

Comment: Did you try either?

Comment: You have asked 14 questions and gotten 17 answers.  But none of those answers have been accepted.  Accepting answers to your questions and upvoting other posts you find useful helps other users find good answers.  You might want to take a moment to go back and remedy that.

Answer (score 5):

Declare the ids in some collection and use [`Contains`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb352880(v=vs.110).aspx) extension method in your query as I show below:

```
Dim ids= New Integer(){1425427, 1440728, 1695324};  
Pols = Pols.Where(Function(x) ids.Contains(x.PolicyId)).ToArray()
```

Comment: You're welcome ;), I noticed now you haven't marked any of your questions yet as as answered. Please, if you feel my answer helped you to solve your problem, consider to check mark the arrow below the voter count.